# How to get first of week based calendar in nodatime?

Tags: calendar, dayofweek, nodatime

I want to get first day of week for specificid ZonedDateTime in NodaTime.
But week starts Saturday in Persian calendar and Monday in Gregorian calendar.

How can I get first day of week based on calendar of ZonedDateTime?

Answer (score 3):

We don't expose that information, because it's not as cut and dried as you expect it to be. Different cultures and contexts use different week rules - for example, while you've stated that the week starts on Monday in the Gregorian calendar, that's context specific. In many contexts Sunday is used as the first day of the week instead.

See the [week numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering) part of the Wikipedia article on weeks for examples of this.

It sounds like you'll probably want a `Dictionary<CalendarSystem, IsoDayOfWeek>` or possibly a `Dictionary<CalendarSystem, IWeekYearRule>` in your application, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You mean I need to write my own collection for start days based on calendar?

Comment: @HomayounBehzadian: Yes, based on your use case - because for some calendars (e.g. Gregorian) there isn't one single "right answer". (Not that you need to implement your own collection class - just create a dictionary.)

Comment: I read about IWeekYearRule. This is not related to question. I just want to know which DayOfWeek is WeekStart based on Zone or calendar

Comment: @HomayounBehzadian: Right - I mentioned it because without knowing more about the bigger picture, it may or may not have been what you wanted. But fundamentally, the answer is "there's no single starting day-of-week for a given calendar and time zone". So again, you need to know what *your application* expects or requires.

Comment: wow! this is very simple. Which day you start to work? Saturday or Monday. There is no need to knowing about how to represent date with week of year and day of week instead month and day in month. In Iran (Zone) working day is Saturday while in France working day starts from Monday

Comment: @HomayounBehzadian: "Which day you start to work?" - that's how *you* define the first day of the week, but that's not how *everyone* does. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering as per my answer - the US deems Sunday to be the first day of the week, as an example, but presumably you'd want to use Monday. That's why Noda Time doesn't get involved in this - **it's an application-specific understanding of what start-of-week means**. If Noda Time decided to follow what *your* application wanted, other users would claim it's buggy because it's not what *they* want.